# Find the sup of an integral succession

Tags: calculus, integration, supremum-and-infimum

Let
$$
a_n=\int^\pi_0e^{-nx}\sin(n^2x)dx
$$

find $\sup\{a_n:n\in\mathbb N\}$

---

I found myself the solution.

Integrating twice by parts we have
$$
a_n=n\int^\pi_0e^{-nx}\cos(n^2x)dx=\left[-e^{-nx}\cos(n^2x)\right]^\pi_{x=0}-n^2\int^\pi_0e^{-nx}\sin(n^2x)dx=1-e^{-n\pi}\cos(n^2\pi)-n^2a_n\\
a_n=\frac{1-e^{-n\pi}\cos(n^2\pi)}{1+n^2}=\frac{1-(-1)^ne^{-n\pi}}{1+n^2}\\
a_{2k}=\frac{1-e^{-2k\pi}}{1+(2k)^2}\\
a_{2k+1}=\frac{1+e^{-(2k+1)\pi}}{1+(2k+1)^2}
$$
then
$$
a_{2k}<a_{2k-1}<a_1=\frac{1+e^{-\pi}}{2}
$$

Comment: Did you compute $a_n$ ? If you did, what I hope and wish, include your result in the post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found myself the solution.

Integrating twice by parts we have
$$
a_n=n\int^\pi_0e^{-nx}\cos(n^2x)dx=\left[-e^{-nx}\cos(n^2x)\right]^\pi_{x=0}-n^2\int^\pi_0e^{-nx}\sin(n^2x)dx=1-e^{-n\pi}\cos(n^2\pi)-n^2a_n\\
a_n=\frac{1-e^{-n\pi}\cos(n^2\pi)}{1+n^2}=\frac{1-(-1)^ne^{-n\pi}}{1+n^2}\\
a_{2k}=\frac{1-e^{-2k\pi}}{1+(2k)^2}\\
a_{2k+1}=\frac{1+e^{-(2k+1)\pi}}{1+(2k+1)^2}
$$
then
$$
a_{2k}<a_{2k-1}<a_1=\frac{1+e^{-\pi}}{2}
$$